# text input field with static text at the end, only allowing to enter digits without without text selectable?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to limit text input to the beginning of the input field while maintaining text next to it static?

Not limiting the over all character count like most questions are posted.

```
<input type="text" id="time" value="0 min"/>
```

So to allow only entering single or double digits for the amount of minutes, without the remaining part " min" to be selectable by the cursor in the input field, as to make the data entry more focused on the digits.

Otherwise I would have to use only the input field for minutes digits and display the word "min" after the field, which I know how to but I figured it would look nicer to show that word statically inside the input field (I also know how to prevent wrong input with regex).

**Maybe there is a way instead of using logic to display the word "min" over the field?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ZBow/pen/VwBdXzN)

If you don't want 'min' to be part of the editable input value, then don't put it in the value.  The min and max attributes can be set to keep the value positive and max double digits.

```
<input type="number" id="time" size="1" min="0" max="99" value="0"/>
<span>min</span>
```

If you want to hide the spin buttons on the number input, add to your css:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

You can of course use css to help with the overall look of the input field.

Also note that an input type of number is generally only recommended for an "amount" of something.  So it would work here for an amount of minutes.  Otherwise, you can use input type of text and the same principle applies, you just wouldn't have to remove the spin buttons and you'd use the maxlength attribute:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2" id="time" size="1" value="0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if it were possible to have 'min' part of the input field, but being non editable while the value input remains editable, sorry could have used that emphasis to make it more clear. =) I take it's (likely) not possible and thus adding the word after the input field is the way to go, your additional spin buttons though are nice though, thanks! If no one else posts an answer or confirmation than I'll accept your answer.

Comment: If you simply want it to appear to be in the box, then you can utilize position.  https://codepen.io/ZBow/pen/VwBdXzN.  It's slightly awkward from a UI / user perspective, because I would expect that 'min' to be editable if it's in the box.

Comment: brilliant, thanks, exactly what I was asking for, with a fixed width on input it will look better. https://codepen.io/ZBow/pen/VwBdXzN I'm still trying to decide whether this is the best UI/UX, I would think that devs like us would expect this but a regular user not necessarily always would expect to edit the text next to a number in an input field with purpose to enter numbers/minutes (which can be prevented via regex and resetting value back to original). I just thought it might look nicer to have descriptive labels in the field when one uses already several input fields.

Comment: btw. it certainly solves/prevents also another issue of having to otherwise remove the text for calculation of that value (i.e. using replace with '') since the inputs value only contains the value. 
The only issue I can see is that clicking into the text won't trigger editing the numbers, could that possibly be enforced?

Comment: With some JS, using a click event and select method - codepen.io/ZBow/pen/VwBdXzN. btw, if you made edits to the codepen and didn't save then I'm just seeing my original one.  I updated this so that the container div has the click event.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, much appreciated, this makes it a much more attractive alternative that works well. Sorry I thought when I clicked share it would have saved the current edited code, tbh. even after registering on codepen I still couldn't find a saving button, I'll need to google it lol (i guess I need to 'fork' it), that's why I prefer https://jsfiddle.net/markusd1984/81jpbqwt/1/ with auto versioning, so much easier.